# How do I avoid redefining the parent element class in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a CSS block similar to that below which defines common styles for `element-a[ace]`:

```
.element-a .element-aa, .element-a .element-ac, .element-a .element-ae {
     /* ... some styling */
}
```

Is it possible to avoid redefining `element-a` or a neater way of doing it all together.

Comment: Look into Less or Sass – they exist for exactly this kind of situation.

Comment: I have tried them both for bigger web apps but this is mobile and was looking for something a bitter lighter and simpler. I see your point though, css doesn't really encourage DRYness itself.

Comment: Well, it does, actually. It depends on you. Maybe you're doing it wrong, you can just assign to your elements a shared class called `common-a` and definite for that class the common CSS. Why do you have all those classes, for example?

Comment: CSS itself doesn't have a way to repeat a parent specification without repeating it for each separate selector.  One might ask if you need the parent in the CSS rule.  Are there `.element-aa` objects that don't have a `.element-a` parent that you're trying to avoid styling?  Or can you just use `.element-aa, .element-ac` etc... without the parent class?

Comment: @jfriend00 I admit it's a bit strange, the reason I am using them is because I am using jquery mobile and need to increase specificity to ensure some of my themes aren't ignored in-favor of the framework css values. It may be true that there is a better way though.

Comment: @Entropy although I may be doing it wrong but I don't think it can be argued that CSS promotes DRYness seen as there is no such thing as a variable or a 'function'. However i fully appreciate that there were other design considerations which took priority.

Comment: If you're only doing it for CSS specificity reasons, can you add `!important` to each rule instead?

Comment: jfriend00 looked into this but guideline I have read imply `important!` is a bit of a "hack" that can be avoided if specificity, and the other rules are used correctly.

Comment: Well, if you want to be specific with jQuery why don't you use IDs and assign to them all a single class? I mean, classes aren't the only way to be specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the following `.element-a div[class*='element-a']`. The above example presuppose that the descendant class is applied in a `div`, of course you can change it to whatever you use.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/yPBcR/1

Comment: I guess this would also pick up `.element-a .element-ab`?

Comment: The class attribute doesn't have a `.` in it, that's the CSS notation but not the HTML one.

Comment: @whatsthebeef check the demo to understand better what happens.

Comment: Although you have answered the original question I am more interested in selecting some elements, namely `element-a[acd]` while ignoring others such as `.element-a .element-ab`

Comment: @whatsthebeef  You could use the css3 `:not()` selector but the efficiency depends on the amount of elements you wish to exclude and the support of internet explorer. Here an example http://jsfiddle.net/yPBcR/2/